# Send Keys to Textarea title Seleium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to send some text to the search textarea at Google Adwords [Keyplanner tool](https://adwords.google.com/ko/KeywordPlanner/Home?__c=4774878911&__u=1416042853&authuser=0&__o=cues#search) using Selenium python.

When inputting manually the text from textarea goes to its attribute 'title'. 
The textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea class="spl-a sprb-c spl-d" rows="1" id="gwt-debug-keywords-text-area" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-94 gwt-uid-74" wrap="off" style="overflow: hidden;" dir="ltr" title="mytext"></textarea>
```

As a result:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('textarea').send_keys('mytext')
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id('gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').send_keys('mytext')
```

produces

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Is there another way to send keys to this search textarea? I have like 500 keywords which I need to grab data for.

full code of text area:

```
<div class="spl-c spI-d" style="width: 575px;">
<div id="gwt-uid-119" class="sprb-a">
<div class="sprb-b spl-b" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">For example, flowers or used cars</div>
<textarea id="gwt-debug-keywords-text-area" class="spl-a sprb-c spl-d" rows="1" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-139 gwt-uid-119" style="overflow: hidden;" dir="ltr" title="my keyword" wrap="off"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you do me a favor and try opening the console window the run the following script $("#textarea").val("mytext").change();

Comment: Your code is wrong, textarea is not an id, but a tag, and val is not a function. What's jquery has to do with selenium webdriver?

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using the id? Have you verified that the `TEXTAREA` is the only one on the page? Try `$$("textarea").length` in the Chrome dev console and see if it returns 1. My guess is that it doesn't and it might be that the first one in the DOM is not visible.

Comment: I've tried id ofc, just copypasted the tag name since it was the last thing I've tried. Added this to the initial question as well. $$("textarea").length -> tried, it returns

Comment: It returns ??? Your answer isn't posted.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to be visible? That seems like the next step. It's hard to tell without being able to see the page. Are you sure you have the right element? Are you sure the element you have actually becomes visible?

Comment: It never becomes visible. It has multiple wraps and somehow it handles the data input and then changes the title of textarea. Also added full code to the question

Comment: If it never becomes visible, then Selenium can't interact with it. You need to find the actual element that a user would type into and `.sendKeys()` into it.

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to interact with is but addressable by Selenium, because it is inside a div which is hidden - this one:

```
<div class="sprb-b spl-b" style="display: none;" ...
```

There is another element which is actually taking the user's input - look for elements with keypress event handlers, and also what changes in DOM web you enter characters.